# Why am I missing some of indexes in list when I print by its equivalent negative indexes in python?

Tags: python, indexing

```
list2 = ["money heist" , [2] , 1, 0.045, (5*3), -18%(-6*2), 0.345]

print(list2[0:])

list2[-5] = "Game OF Thrones"

print(list2[-5:])
```

output as follows:

```
['money heist', [2], 1, 0.045, 15, -6, 0.345]
['Game OF Thrones', 0.045, 15, -6, 0.345]
```

What happened to `[2]` and `1` ??

[image]

Answer (score 3):

In the line:

```
list2[-5] = 'Game of Thrones'
```

you replaced the 3rd (fifth from the back: `-5`) entry `1` with `'Game of Thrones'`.

Then, with

```
print(list2[-5:])
```

you start printing from the fifth last element onwards (`-5:`), which means your output is correct. `[2]` is not printed since it's skipped, and `1` is changed to another value.

Answer (score 0):

Let's break it down:

```
list2 = ["money heist" , [2] , 1, 0.045, (5*3), -18%(-6*2), 0.345]
```

`print(list2[0:])` will obviously print the whole list, because the index starts at `0`.

Calling `list2[-5] = "Game OF Thrones"` will overwrite the fifth last, or in this case, 
third element of the list into `"Game OF Thrones"`.

So you get `list2 = ["money heist", [2], "Game OF Thrones", 0.045, (5*3), -18%(-6*2), 0.345]`

Finally, when you run `print(list2[-5:])`, 
you tell python to print everything from the list starting at index `2` *(the third element)*:

```
["Game OF Thrones" , 0.045, (5*3), -18%(-6*2), 0.345]
```